# Terraform: GCP: Purpose of quotes around resource.label.\"xxxx"\?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, syntax, terraform

In this document
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics

There is an example for

**Alerting on the ratio of quota-usage to quota-limit**

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics#ap-quota-limit

From the example: The line below is putting quotes around the word "service" in the resource label.  Can anyone explain the purpose of this? I understand what the back slash is for.  Escaping the quotes, but why can't you just write resource.label.xxxxxx?  Is this some sort of interpolation? I can't seem to google it correctly.

```
"filter": "metric.type=\"serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage\" resource.type=\"consumer_quota\" resource.label.\"service\"=\"iam.googleapis.com\"",
```

Answer (score 2):

In terraform, the use of the quotes is explained in [Escape Sequences](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/strings.html). Specifically, using `\"` in `filter` value allows you to write:

> Literal quote (without terminating the string)

So filter will have value of:

```
metric.type="serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage" resource.type="consumer_quota" resource.label."service"="iam.googleapis.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more specific.  I understand how escaping works (I think).  What I don't understand is what the string is for in the key name here.

`resource.label.\"service\"`

What does having a string do here that `resource.label.service` does not?